# Inserting JsonObject at a define index in JsonArray

Tags: java

```
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class RowAnswer {
     private String row ;
     private String serviceName ;
     private JSONObject serviceResponse ;


 }
```

The above pojo has a row and a serviceResponse and i have a List, i want to insert the serviceResponse at given row(position) number of a master jsonArray.
So , it is like inserting jsonObject at defined position of jsonArray . I am doing it this way but this doesnt seem optimized .

```
 public void merge(JSONObject masterObject, List<RowAnswer> completeList) {
         completeDetailsfromRecommendationApis.stream().forEach(rowAnswer -> {
             try {
                 HomePageUtil.addToPos(rowAnswer , completeContent );
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
     }


public static void addToPos(RowAnswer rowAnswer, JSONObject completeContent ) throws JSONException {
        int pos = Integer.valueOf(rowAnswer.getRow()) ;
        JSONObject jsonObj = rowAnswer.getServiceResponse() ;
        JSONArray jsonArr = completeContent.optJSONArray("container");
    for (int i = jsonArr.length(); i > pos; i--){


            jsonArr.put(i, jsonArr.get(i-1));

    }

        jsonArr.put(pos, jsonObj);



}

Is there any other optimized way to do this .
```